# Where to add UI objects when programmatically creating UI (instead of .xib/storyboard)

Tags: ios, objective-c

In the UIViewControllers where I don't use .xib files, I've been creating my UI elements in the viewDidLoad methods. E.g.,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Setup table
    self.tableView=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.tableView setDataSource:self];
    [self.tableView setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

    // Setup custom cells
    UINib *lessonNib=[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:nil];
    [[self tableView] registerNib:lessonNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCellID"];
}
```

For the most part, this is working fine. But, in the process of investigating a bug associated with dynamic cell heights, I'm curious: is this the appropriate spot to add my UI elements?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: it may be the appropriate place to create and add them - BUT it is not the correct place to set their layout, e.g. their frames.

Comment: Hi @luk2302, thanks for the comment. For frames and other layout elements, is it because no layout elements have been setup yet in viewDidLoad (and so my `self.view.frame` may be empty or otherwise meaningless)? Does that mean `viewWillAppear` is the earliest appropriated spot?

Comment: why viewDidLoad is incorrect for setting frames ? can you give me a reasons? :P

Comment: @JulianKról e.g. the frame property is not valid yet.

Comment: not always, more often than not it will be :)

Comment: that is not sufficient!

Comment: NO! You should get your facts right: how does **YOUR** code react to frame changes if you layout your UI in viewDidLoad? - "it does not"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it is the right place, yes. Since this method is only called once for sure and is called before anything of your view is shown on screen. And therefore you don´t risk creating them twice or even more often or too late.

But your layout should be done at a different place - in [`viewWillLayoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillLayoutSubviews):

> When a view's bounds change, the view adjusts the position of its subviews. Your view controller can override this method to make changes before the view lays out its subviews. The default implementation of this method does nothing.

You could also overwrite the corresponding `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Regarding your comment: yes, layout information is not yet present in `viewDidLoad`, `self.view.frame` for example is not guaranteed to be the actual frame that your view will be displayed in later on. Further more a frame change by some part of your code would cause your UI to not respond if you set their size and position only on load.

*Note:* Setting up your subviews via code is far more tedious than just designing them in a storyboard - I would heavily recommend that if you  don´t have serious concerns against using them.

Comment: "You should override this method only if the autoresizing and constraint-based behaviors of the subviews do not offer the behavior you want" - so you are not correct :P

Comment: He is not using constraints or auto-resizing - therefore i am in fact correct.

Comment: it should be done in layoutSubviews if you really have something that needs to be finally customized so I disagree that setting in viewDidLoad is a bad place for this :)

Comment: moreover you mentioned a method that do not exists in UIViewController so you are totally wrong. Probably you wanted to mention viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: Hmm, yes, you are right about that one. :/ I somehow wrote the corresponding method on UIView.

Comment: apart that, he didn't mention any rotations so overriding this viewDidLayoutSubviews method shouldn't be the case. I think in 90% viewDidLoad will me more than enough.

Comment: I had this exact issue today while testing code on iPhone 5s compared to iPhone 6 - on one screen the frame is correct, on the other one the frame was around 80 pixels too short.

Comment: if you were setting frames by setting points then for two different devices you need different settings that is obvious. You are still wrong in your answer :( the quotation is for different method and read documentation carefully what it states for `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Generally your answer is misleading and wrong

Comment: @JulianKról If not `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, then is there another method that would give 100% reliability in cases like the question's example? (I.e., getting a `UITableView` to fit the frame of the `UIViewController`'s view on all devices.)

Comment: @JulianKról It has nothing to with devices. In my case I add a overlay layer `_overlayLayer.path = CGPathCreateWithRect(self.view.frame, NULL);` in viewDidLoad. **That code does not work.**

Comment: Final word: viewDidLayoutSubviews will do the trick but I wanted to say that I wouldn't start there at the beginning as viewDidLoad might be sufficient :) Anyway I do not see the point why do not use the auto layout and do not create a separate class for a view and assign it in loadView to self.view and encapsulate UI stuff in UIView. That is fixing most of the issues. Put the work on the system. Good luck guys

Comment: @luk2302 Thanks for answering the Q and for the additional info about `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. Much appreciated!